Next.js useRouter().back() causing NotFoundError in a client-side component
I’m working on a Next.js project and I’m using the useRouter() hook to navigate between pages. In one of my client-side components, I’m trying to use the back() method from useRouter() to handle navigation when the user clicks a custom back button. However, I’m encountering a NotFoundError when the back() method is triggered.
Here’s my current setup:
"use client";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const CustomBackButton: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const { back } = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const onBackClick = useCallback(() => {
    if (pathname !== "/") {
      back();
    }
  }, [back, pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("back-btn")?.addEventListener("click", onBackClick);

    return () => {
      document.getElementById("back-btn")?.removeEventListener("click", onBackClick);
    };
  }, [onBackClick]);

  return <button id="back-btn">Go Back</button>;
};

export default CustomBackButton;

The error I’m encountering:

Unhandled Runtime Error
NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.

What could be causing this NotFoundError, and how can I resolve it while using useRouter().back() for navigation?
nextjs version: 14.2.13
i need setup hanndle back use useRouter

are using app router ?

In Next.js, the back() method trigger the browser to attempt to navigate to the previous entry inthe history stack, but if there is no previous entry, the NotFoundError can occur because there's nowhere to go back to. To solve the issue, you can check browser histry entry is available to back and if it's not available, you can redirect users to a special page such as home page.
I updated your code like below.
"use client";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const CustomBackButton: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const { back, push } = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const onBackClick = useCallback(() => {
    if (window.history.length > 1 && pathname !== "/") {
      // Use the back() method if history is available
      back();
    } else {
      // Redirect to the "/" page, you can adjust it
      push("/");
    }
  }, [back, push, pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("back-btn")?.addEventListener("click", onBackClick);

    return () => {
      document.getElementById("back-btn")?.removeEventListener("click", onBackClick);
    };
  }, [onBackClick]);

  return <button id="back-btn">Go Back</button>;
};

export default CustomBackButton;


const onBackClick = useCallback(() => {
if (window.history.length > 1 && pathname !== "/") {
// Use the back() method if history is available
back();
} else {
// Redirect to the "/" page, you can adjust it
push("/");
}
}, [back, push, pathname]);
i try use push but get same error
Unhandled Runtime Error
NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.

thank you, resolve with fixe on layout
